# template-id does not match any template declaration GNU gcc compiler

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a openGL program. I only get errors in this header file. The error is "error: template-id 'method ' for 'void VertexBufferLayout::method(unsigned int)' does not match any template declaration" I'am clueless of what to do.

I've tried to but the templates in the class with no success.

```
class VertexBufferLayout
{
private:
    std::vector<VertexBufferElement> m_Elements;
    unsigned int m_Stride;
public:
    VertexBufferLayout()
        : m_Stride(0) {}

    public:
    template <typename T>
    void method(T obj)
   {
//       static_assert(false);
    }

    inline const std::vector<VertexBufferElement> GetElement() const { return m_Elements; }
    inline unsigned int GetStride() const { return m_Stride; }
};

template<>
void VertexBufferLayout::method<float>(unsigned int count)
{
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Elements.push_back({ GL_FLOAT, count, false });
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Stride += VertexBufferElement::GetSizeOfType(GL_FLOAT);
}

template<>
void VertexBufferLayout::method<unsigned int>(unsigned int count)
{
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Elements.push_back({ GL_UNSIGNED_INT, count, false });
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Stride += VertexBufferElement::GetSizeOfType(GL_UNSIGNED_INT);
}

template<>
void VertexBufferLayout::method<unsigned char>(unsigned int count)
{
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Elements.push_back({ GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, count, true });
    VertexBufferLayout::m_Stride += VertexBufferElement::GetSizeOfType(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

}
```

The error is "error: template-id 'method ' for 'void VertexBufferLayout::method(unsigned int)' does not match any template declaration"

Answer (score 1):

What type of `T` is here, `float` or `unsigned int`?

```
VertexBufferLayout::method<float>(unsigned int count)
```

It's the classic copy-paste error. I guess it must be

```
VertexBufferLayout::method<float>(float count)
```

The later line has the same error

```
void VertexBufferLayout::method<unsigned char>(unsigned int count)
```

must be

```
void VertexBufferLayout::method<unsigned char>(unsigned char count)
```